# Hibernate performance issue with multi level data set

Tags: performance, hibernate

I have following set of data:

```
Class-
      |- Section
      |         |- Student1
      |         |         |-Day1Details
      |         |         |-Day2Details   
      |         |- Student2
      |         |         |-Day1Details
      |         |         |-Day2Details  
      |- Section
                :
                :
```

I am using Hibernate ORM to persist above sample data into db. When we try to retrieve this data hibernate execute query for each student separately. So if there are 1000 Students it will fire 1000 queries to get the entire data set and it is affecting the performance of the applications due to large number of i/o s to DB.

I want this data to be collected in following few queries.

```
select class,section, students from c,s,stu where student.sec=s.sec and s.class = c.class

select day_details from day_details_tab where student in (studentId from above query).
```

Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Strange thing is that , It only executes separate query at day details level. rest of the data gets fetched with joins...

Answer (score 0):

The usage of joins and associations in HQL is described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). The correct query to load everything at once is:

```
 select clazz from Clazz clazz
 left join fetch clazz.sections section
 left join fetch section.students student
 left join fetch student.dayDetails
```

HQL uses entities and associations. Never table and column names as you're doing in your question.

Comment: joining all the data at once at database side may also affect performance of DB server if volume of data is high...

Comment: Some How I want to run it in two different queries.

Comment: So you think loading the same data using two queries will affect performance less than using just one? Doesn't make much sense. Anyway, you're pre-optimizing, which is the root of all evil. Only optimize if you have a proven performance problem, and if you can prove that the problem comes from the query. Anyway, I already showed you how to write the first query. Writing the second one should be easy.